# How to unconditionally recompile with automake's Makefiles

Tags: makefile, automake

I have a project using autoconf/automake. Sometimes I want to remake part of it even though  make (correctly) believes all dependencies are up-to-date. For other projects I can use `make -W some-file.c` to ask make to pretend that `some-file.c` is new and rebuild accordingly. (Option `-W` is also called `--what-if`, `--new-file` and `--assume-new`.) However this doesn't work with automake's Makefiles - nothing happens, as if the option is ignored. Is there any way to get this feature working?

I am using automake (GNU automake) 1.16.2 and  autoconf (GNU Autoconf) 2.69

Example configure.ac

```
#                                               -*- Autoconf -*-
# Process this file with autoconf to produce a configure script.

AC_PREREQ([2.69])
AC_INIT([FULL-PACKAGE-NAME], [VERSION], [BUG-REPORT-ADDRESS])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([zot.c])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_PROG_CC
AC_OUTPUT
```

Example Makefile.am

```
bin_PROGRAMS=zot
zot_SOURCES=zot.c
```

Example zot.c file

```
int main() { return 0;}
```

Example session

```
$ ./configure && make
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
```

(autoconf output omitted)

```
config.status: executing depfiles commands
make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/meo'
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.     -g -O2 -MT zot.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/zot.Tpo -c -o zot.o zot.c
mv -f .deps/zot.Tpo .deps/zot.Po
gcc  -g -O2   -o zot zot.o  
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/meo'
$ make
make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/meo'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/meo'
```

I would expect the following command to re-compile zot.c and re-link

```
$ make -W zot.c
make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/meo'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/meo'
```

however make does not do anything as everything were up to date.

Comment: Perhaps -W doesn't propagate to recursive make invocations. Could try `make -B` (--always-make), which I recall does propagate. Of course that causes make to assume everything is out-of-date. Might be able to limit the rebuild scope by adding the specific target you want to rebuild, like `make -B zot.o`, or `make -B libzot.a`, or just `make -B zot`.

Comment: That may be the reason, thanks for the swift reply. `-B` does indeed assume everything is out of date, to the extent of re-running `./configure` which is a bit too much!

Comment: Seeing as the recursive make command is `make  all-am`, perhaps you can simply do `make all-am -W zot.c`. Fragile, but might work.

Comment: Conventional, and independent of the choice of `make` implementation, would be `touch zot.c; make`.  Of course, that works by modifying the timestamp of the file so that all targets depending on it really are out of date.

Comment: Andreas, unfortunately `make all-am -W zot.c` doesn't do anything either. Seems that automake keeps its dependency info in `.deps/XXX.Po` files so I think I need -W to be in force when it comes to process `.deps/zot.Po`

Comment: John, I agree that would work but I actually wanted to use it with `--dry-run` just to see what would be made, without changing anything. I suppose I could try `make --touch` to quickly do a 'fake' build?

Comment: To tag someone in a comment you need the '@' before the name. Else there is no notification.

Comment: In retrospect, making it work with --dry-run is a detail worthwhile having mention in the question itself. Disqualifies several potential solutions/workarounds.